# python ошибка при парсинге

Tags: python, request, bs4

Когда пытаюсь получить элемент по классу, возвращает none

```
if "https" in name:
    html1 = requests.get(name, headers=headers).text
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html1, "lxml")
    element = soup1.find("td", class_="price height-column-with-price price-highlighted")
    print(element)
```

что делать, как решать проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `None` не ошибка. Функция `find` вернет `None`, если не найден элемент. Предоставьте минимальный пример кода, чтобы можно было его запустить. Кст, проверьте что в `html1` находится именно то, что ожидаете, т.к. сайт может данные подгружать, тогда решать другим способом

Comment: Ссылку на сайт предоствьте